# How to pause/continue NSThread

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an app, where i use function FSMoveObjectToTrashSync. It works in background thread. I need ability for my app, to click on button to pause it or continue(if it paused) how i can make it?
Example of code:

```
NSMutableArray *fileArray = [NSMutableArray array withobjects:@"file1url", @"file2", @"file3", nil]; 
NSMutableArray *threadArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

-(void)myFunc{
   for (NSURL *url in fileArray){
        NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(mySelectorWith:) object:url];
        [thread start];
        [threadArray addObject:thread];
   }
}

-(void)mySelectorWith:(NSURL *) url{
       FSRef source;
       FSPathMakeRef((const UInt8 *)[[url path] fileSystemRepresentation], &source, NULL);
       FSMoveObjectToTrashSync(&source, NULL, kFSFileOperationDefaultOptions);
}
```

PS:sorry for my english, i'm from Belarus... =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to replace the `for` loop on a single thread with an NSOperation subclass. Each operation should trash exactly one object; you then create one operation for each object you want to trash and put all of the operations on an NSOperationQueue.

The operation queue will run each operation on a thread, and it can even run multiple operations on multiple threads if it sees enough computing power laying around to do it.

[An operation queue can be paused and resumed at will](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/setSuspended%3a); when you suspend the queue, any operations in that queue that are already running will finish, but no more will start until you resume the queue.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an NSConditionLock. An NSConditionLock is similar to a condition variable. It has a couple of basic methods, lockWhenCondition, and unlockWithCondition, and lock. A typical usage is to have your background thread waiting on the condition lock with "lockWhenCondition:", and the in you foreground thread to set the condition, which causes the background thread to wake up. The condition is a simple integer, usually an enumeration.

Here's an example:

```
enum {
    kWorkTodo = 1,
    kNoWorkTodo = 0
}

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        theConditionLock = [[NSConditionLock alloc] initWithCondition: kNoWorkTodo];
        workItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)startDoingWork {
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(doBackgroundWork) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void)doBackgroundWork:(id)arg {
    while (YES) {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        NSArray *items = nil;
        [theConditionLock lockWhenCondition:kWorkTodo]; // Wait until there is work to do
        items = [NSArray arrayWithArray:workItems]
        [workItems removeAllObjects];
        [theConditionLock unlockWithCondition:kNoWorkTodo];
        for(id item in items) {
            // Do some work on item.
        }
        [pool drain];
    }
}

- (void)notifyBackgroundThreadAboutNewWork {
    [theConditionLock lock];
    [workItems addObject:/* some unit of work */];
    [theConditionLock unlockWithCondition:kWorkTodo];
}
```

In this example, when startDoingWork is called doBackgroundWork: will start on a background thread, but then stop because there isn't any work to do. Once notifyBackgroundThreadAboutNewWork is called, then doBackgroundWork: will fire up and process the new work, and then go back to sleep waiting for new work to be available, which will happen the next time notifyBackgroundThreadAboutNewWork is called.